# How to add text to a cell in sheets app without using the formula 'bar'

Tags: google-sheets, android

Currently, by default, when I enter text in a cell in the sheets app there is no text entry marker in a cell, although there is one in the formula 'bar'. This makes it impossible to enter text without using the formula bar, which only shows one line of text at a time, which is not good for entering more than one line of text/data. I have downloaded Microsoft excel, the equivalent app, and it does have a flashing text entry marker in the cell itself, which is far more helpful. I would prefer to use Google Sheets for the sake of convenience, but will use excel if I can't either find a way to avoid using the formula bar, or even better, removing it entirely.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. I’m voting to close this question because it's about using a mobile app. Questions about the Google Sheets app for Android are off-topic in Web Applications SE. They might be on-topic in [android.se].

Answer (score 0):

Give a doble click to the cell :)

BTW: the formula bar can be enlarged

[image: formula bar]

Comment: Thanks I will try again